# Alternative function of cv2.drawContours(*args) in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

Is there any other way in Python to fill in the contents of a contour besides using OpenCV?

```
cv2.drawContours(mask, [a_contour], -1, 255, -1)
```

I find it rather difficult to believe that this is the only way to do it. I've in PIL, skimage etc but have not found anything.

Comment: Do you mean filling or drawing ?

In Python, the contour coordinates are directly accessible as lists, and you can implement your own drawing function using your favorite graphics toolset.

Comment: with this function in opencv, one can draw white the pixels lying inside the contour. how this can be done using PIL or skimage or other libraries?

Comment: [scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes.html) could work

Comment: Apparently, you neglected my question and did not understand my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought by using the word 'fill' in my question was  clear

Answer (score 1):

The `cv2.drawContour` fills a contour with some values, the contour being a list of coordinates not necessarily matching the pixel granularity, it is to say that the coordinates can be floating numbers.

In skimage, the output of the `find_contour` algorithm can also be used as a polygon and you can 'draw' - in the meaning of filling it - using the `skimage.draw.polygon` function to obtain the same result as the `cv2.drawContour`.

Here is a simple example code:

```py
# contour is one contour of the image as generated by the find_contour function
# img is the original image

# the img.shape is limiting the size of the polygon to be inside the image.
rr, cc = skimage.draw.polygon(contour[:,0], contour[:,1], img.shape)

# in this way you set the value of each pixel inside the polygon to 1
# or to whatever you want. 
img[rr,cc] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/) Check out these filters:

1. [Filling holes](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_holes_and_peaks.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-features-detection-plot-holes-and-peaks-py) (I think this is the best fit for your problem)
2. Or you could use combination of [Contour finding](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-edges-plot-contours-py) and [Flood Fill](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_floodfill.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-floodfill-py)